# Not getting Rep Notification for new up votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notifications

So just a little while ago i was flipping out because i was 2 rep away from my 10k rep goal

[image: My Rep]

but then all of a sudden it was then 10,008 rep because someone upvoted me. however i didn't get any notification about this +10

[[image: Today's Notifications[2]][image: Yesterday's (under all the Yearlings)]

[image: My Rep Page for the past 2 days]

now as you can see in the screenshots above, over the past 2 days i got 2 upvotes to a question i posted, however the notifications only shows 1 +10 notification. and they system knows i got the upvote because i knew that i now have access to mod tools.

I am on a Windows 10 Laptop using Chrome 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The hamsters are currently a little overworked with calculating rep so that’s probably why

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Our aggregator is backlogged from the massive rep recalc throughout the afternoon. We peaked around 9 million items in the event queue and it's chewing through them. It's currently down to 7.9 million items and will likely take all night to finish:
[image: aggregator]

It's a first in, first out in-order queue, so we're about 5 hours behind and recent vote events will be at least that far behind as it chews through.

For anyone curious, the reason these items are taking a while is each is a lot of work. In the "reputation was recalced" case, we do a diff on the aggregated event table (`NetworkRepHistory`) compared to the per-site table (`RepHistory`) and do a delta and update the network table. This network table is how your top bar quickly shows rep across all sites. This is one of the most expensive a run items, but is usually a rare one. But today, it wasn't really rare.

The best option here, in my opinion, is to let this naturally flush out overnight. I apologize for the delays and annoyance, but I believe this to be the path with the fewest risks and question marks.

Comment: Does it work for Dvotes too ? I didn't see -2 either  there. I am aware that it is not notified of, but it should display if the burger is opened, right ?

Comment: Yep this affects pretty much all global events, upvotes, downvotes, everything is one queue that needs to play in-order.

Comment: Can't you at least add global notification that there won't be notifications? ;)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard 6 to 8 weeks later: *Our internal queue is overflown with rep recals and further notifications will experience a delay of up to 6 to 8 weeks* :)

Comment: @iBug I smell a bug... ;)