# Is the achievements dropdown broken again, after the questions rep update?

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

Is that just me, or is the achievements counter going totally bonkers?

It shows me a single -2 from SO, and totally ignores votes coming in for MSE?

(somehow doesn't come as surprise, and I kinda feel that this complete recount will result in plenty other glitches here or there)

Comment: +1, it's broken for me as well.

Comment: I think there may be a dupe somewhere... but if I remember correctly, the recalc is still running and the achievements are in the same queue so they're going to all be delayed until the recalc for the entire network is done... or something like that... check Nick's answers... this one, I think: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338196/not-getting-rep-notification-for-new-up-votes

Comment: A similar question of [Not getting Rep Notification for new up votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338196/not-getting-rep-notification-for-new-up-votes) (with it being marked as a duplicate of 2 other questions) likely deals with the same basic underlying issue, i.e., the system being overloaded doing all of the question reputation, and related other changes, recalculations across the system.