# Not complaining, but I just gained 500 points without reason

Tags: support, reputation

Last night I received 500 points extra without any (to me know) particular reason.

I still had a browser open so here's a screenshot of my stats of yesterday:

[image]

and currently it's:

[image]

with no actual trace of any cause.

Does anybody know what could have happened?

Answer (score 2):

See

https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1

And

[Not getting Rep Notification for new up votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338196/not-getting-rep-notification-for-new-up-votes)

Basically, you're getting more rep for your previous question, but the notification of rep gains is delayed.